# Not adding data to associated table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, associations

With the code below and entry is created in the venuetypes table with the correct *venue_id* and time stamps however, the *type* column remains as *null*

```
def new
    @new1 = "gfdsgfd"
    @venue = Venue.new
    @venue.save
    @venuetype = @venue.venuetypes.create(:type => "test")
    @venuetype.save
    respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @venue }
end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you've specified otherwise, rails expects a `type` column to be used for [single table inheritance](http://code.alexreisner.com/articles/single-table-inheritance-in-rails.html) which is probably causing problems.

Also, `venuetypes.create` will only save the venue type if it is created successfully, as will the `.save` call afterwards. You have almost certainly got an error on the venue type which is causing it not to be saved. Try using `.save!` which will throw an error or by lookins at `@venuetype.errors` which will contain any error messages that have caused it not to be saved.